# Point cloud library missing header files after vcpkg installation

Tags: vcpkg, concave-hull

I am quite a beginner to programming so I am sorry for my basic question.

I installed PCL 11.1 via vcpkg manager a few weeks ago and now I have realized I am missing some header files. In particular  pcl/surface/concave_hull.h and some more regarding visualisation but these I don't miss that much for now.

I have tried to install PCL (v11.1) in a different way (using exe file which I found on git) and I can see the missing files there. Nevertheless when I add this location  to additional include directories in visual studio (v16.8.4)I got 3 Linker errors.

```
 Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl pcl::ConcaveHull<struct pcl::PointXYZ>::performReconstruction(struct pcl::PolygonMesh &)" (?performReconstruction@?$ConcaveHull@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@MEAAXAEAUPolygonMesh@2@@Z) Meas3D  C:\Users\hribh\source\repos\Meas3D\Meas3D\Meas3D\hull.obj   1

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl pcl::ConcaveHull<struct pcl::PointXYZ>::performReconstruction(class std::vector<struct pcl::Vertices,class std::allocator<struct pcl::Vertices> > &)" (?performReconstruction@?$ConcaveHull@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@MEAAXAEAV?$vector@UVertices@pcl@@V?$allocator@UVertices@pcl@@@std@@@std@@@Z)   Meas3D  C:\Users\hribh\source\repos\Meas3D\Meas3D\Meas3D\hull.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl pcl::ConcaveHull<struct pcl::PointXYZ>::reconstruct(class pcl::PointCloud<struct pcl::PointXYZ> &,class std::vector<struct pcl::Vertices,class std::allocator<struct pcl::Vertices> > &)" (?reconstruct@?$ConcaveHull@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@QEAAXAEAV?$PointCloud@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@2@AEAV?$vector@UVertices@pcl@@V?$allocator@UVertices@pcl@@@std@@@std@@@Z) Meas3D  C:\Users\hribh\source\repos\Meas3D\Meas3D\Meas3D\hull.obj   1
```

Does anybody know why is that and how to install complete version of PCL through vcpkg or how to get rid of those errors? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with header files.
Turned out, that using vcpkg does not provide all the headers and files.
You can install pcl all in one from here, this solved my problem: http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl181/
I know that it is a basic answer, but I hope it can help.